# ASP.NET MVC: Pass parameters to default route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, url-routing

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC application as an API for my mobile application.
I'm going to send some parameters using http `GET` method.

When I debug my application, `http://localhost:58757/` is mapped to `http://localhost:58757/home/index`.But I don't know how to send parameters to controllers of home . Currently I use its complete URL i.e. `http://localhost:58757/home/index?userID=10&language=en` to pass parameters. I want to know are there any methods so I can remove `/home/index` from this URL and still passing parameters?

Comment: You just leave it out, just like without parameters

Comment: can you post your route configuration pelase

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assigning multiple routes to the same controller or action in ASP MVC 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35296018/assigning-multiple-routes-to-the-same-controller-or-action-in-asp-mvc-6)

Comment: @SimonPrice, That link has nothing to do with OP's issue, not to mention the question is tagged MVC-4

Comment: What is wrong with using `http://localhost:58757?userID=10&language=en`?

Comment: And if your creating a link in a view - `@Html.ActionLink("...", "Index", "Home", new { userID = 10, language = "en" }, null)`