# Page names with ASP.NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, routes, asp.net-core-mvc

I need the same thing (same page with diffrent urls)
like:
http://localhost:59810/Home/Privacy
http://localhost:59810/Home/Privat

To try I have added the folowering to startup "ConfigureServices" in a brand ned 2.1 project

```
      services.AddMvc()
               .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
               .AddRazorPagesOptions(options => {
                   options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Privacy", "/Privat");

               });

I also did try:

      services.AddMvc()
               .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
               .AddRazorPagesOptions(options => {
                   options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Home/Privacy", "/Home/Privat");

               });
```

But its not working i still get 404 on: http://localhost:59810/Home/Privat

Did i miss something?

Comment: configure it in controller level. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35296018/assigning-multiple-routes-to-the-same-controller-or-action-in-asp-mvc-6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can decorate your action with:

```
 [Route("/Home/Privacy")]
 [Route("/Home/Privat")]
```

You also may find heplpfull this [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `Home/Privacy` exists in your project.

Here is a simple demo like below:

1.Content Structure:

[image]

2.Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
        .AddRazorPagesOptions(options => {
        options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Home/Privacy", "/Home/Privat");

    });
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

3.Privacy.cshtml.cs:

```
public class PrivacyModel : PageModel
{
    public void OnGet()
    {
    }
}
```

4.Result:
[image]