# How to create route with multiple optional string parameters in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-5, asp.net5

I have an application that is written on the top of asp.net core 5/.Net 5 framework. I have a need to create a flexible route that would bind multiple string parameters.

for example, the route would look like this

```
/homes-for-sale-in-los-angeles-100/0-5000_price/condo,apartment_type/0-5_beds/0-4_baths/2_page
```

In the above URL the only required part will be `/homes-for-sale-in-los-angeles-100`. `los-angeles` is the city name and `100` is the id. The rest of it are just parameters. The `0-5000_price` meaning I want to bind the value `0-5000` to a parameter called `price`.

Not always all the parameters are provided. Here are some different shapes of the same route

```
/homes-for-sale-in-los-angeles-100/condo,apartment_type
/homes-for-sale-in-los-angeles-100/0-5000_price/10_page
/homes-for-sale-in-los-angeles-100/condo_type/0-5000_price/2_page
```

Here is what I have done

```
[Route("/homes-for-sale-in-{city}-{id:int}.{filter?}/{page:int?}", Name = "HomesForSaleByCity")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Display(SearchViewModel viewModel)
{
    return View();
}

public class SearchViewModel 
{
    [Required]
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    
    public string City { get; set; }

    public string Price { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }

    public string Beds { get; set; }

    public string Baths { get; set; }

    public int Page { get; set; }
}
```

How can I create a route that would allow multiple optional parameters and bind them correctly?

Comment: Using query string parameters is more suitable in this case. And also u can keep using the `SearchViewModel` like this `public async Task<IActionResult> Display([FromQuery] SearchViewModel viewModel)`

Comment: See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35296018/assigning-multiple-routes-to-the-same-controller-or-action-in-asp-mvc-6

Comment: @Eldar query parameters are not SEO friendly. The URL in the question will provide a natural URL that is SEO friendly

Comment: @jdweng I don't think having multiple route is doable as there are lots of combination these filters. For example, `Price, Type, and beds`, `Price and beds`, `bed and type`.... I am looking for more of a robust solution that would just parse all these parameters and populate what is available

Comment: @Jay then you need a something like a `capture-all` kind of route and a regex processing of route parameters. Like [this](https://keestalkstech.com/2018/02/dotnet-core-mvc-regex-routing-with-named-groups/). It is for old asp.net but it can give you the idea

Comment: @Eldar I tried the following pattern `[Route("/homes-for-sale-in-{city}-{id:int}{*.}", Name = "HomesForSaleByCity")]` but that gives me the following error. I am thinking if I can get the route to map anything that starts with, I'll be apple to manually map the request to the viewmodel. Here is the error that I get `RoutePatternException: A path segment that contains more than one section, such as a literal section or a parameter, cannot contain a catch-all parameter.`

Comment: There is a Request and a Controller.  The Request is a query to the server.  The server may have multiple webpages and the route is the web page to use on the server.  Then the server sends back a response.  The Controller is used to parse the response.  The response has a body which can have multiple class structures.  The body gets deserialized.  These classes are the IActionResult.  When the response is XML the classes must be defined. When the response is JSON a JSON deserialize to not need classes and can be dynamic. You can also have a custom deserialize when response is not JSON or XML.

Comment: I do not know why you need a different route (webpage) for each query.  You client send a request.  Most servers in the URL after the question mark has parameters.  You should have use the parameters for the query into the database which means you need only one route.  Then handle the different responses in the deserializing of the results (IActionResult).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a route definition like this will make it capture all those routes you provided :

```
[Route("homes-for-sale-in-{city}-{id}/{**catchAll}")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> City(string city, string id, string catchAll)
{
  // Here you will parse the catchAll and extract the parameters        
  await Task.Delay(100);
  return this.Ok(catchAll);
}
```

Also please note that `catchAll` parameter can't be made optional. So a request like `/homes-for-sale-in-los-angeles-100/` will result in 404.

Comment: This does not work. Its is throwing the following error `RoutePatternException: A path segment that contains more than one section, such as a literal section or a parameter, cannot contain a catch-all parameter.`

Comment: Actually this code worked! Thank you so much!!

Comment: @Jay I have the same error message. How'd you solve for that?

Comment: Just kidding--I see, you just cannot have a segment after the catch-all...which makes sense!